# molecule image in vscode

Tags: python, rdkit

I try to show my molecule in vscode but it doesn't work. But in jupyter notebook was every thing fine.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

a = Chem.MolFromSmiles("c1cocc1")
b = Chem.AddHs(a)
Draw.MolsToImage([b], legends=["Furan"])
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: "it does not work" is not a sufficient description of your problem. What are you expecting ? How ? What do you get instead ?

Comment: Actually, it should show a molecule named "Furan".

Comment: The terminal shows no error, it just run and shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly display the output of `Draw.MolsToImage` :

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

a = Chem.MolFromSmiles("c1cocc1")
b = Chem.AddHs(a)
furan = Draw.MolsToImage([b], legends=["Furan"])

furan.show()
```